# Filtering an IQueryable in C#

Tags: c#, html, css, razor, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to filter a view of records from my database to only show records that match search filters provided by the user. Here's my code:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchSerial, string searchRoom, decimal searchPrice1, decimal searchPrice2, DateTime searchDate1, DateTime searchDate2)
    {
        var computers = from m in _context.Computers
                        select m;

        
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchSerial))
        {
            computers = computers.Where(s => s.ManufacturerSerialNumber.ToString()!.Equals(searchSerial));

        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchRoom))
        {
            computers = computers.Where(s => s.OfficeRoomNumber!.Equals(searchRoom));

        }
        
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(""+searchPrice1) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(""+searchPrice2))
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty("" + searchPrice1))
            {
                computers = computers.Where(s => !(s.Price > searchPrice2));

            }
            else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty("" + searchPrice2))
            {
                computers = computers.Where(s => !(s.Price < searchPrice1));

            }
            else
            {
                computers = computers.Where(s => !(s.Price < searchPrice1));
                computers = computers.Where(s => !(s.Price > searchPrice2));

            }
        }
        
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(""+searchDate1) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty("" + searchDate2))
        {
           
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty("" + searchDate1))
            {
                computers = computers.Where(s => !(s.InstallationDate.CompareTo(searchDate2) < 0));

            }
            else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty("" + searchDate2))
            {
                computers = computers.Where(s => !(s.InstallationDate.CompareTo(searchDate1) > 0));

            }
            else
            {
                computers = computers.Where(s => !(s.InstallationDate.CompareTo(searchDate2) < 0));
                computers = computers.Where(s => !(s.InstallationDate.CompareTo(searchDate1) > 0));

            }
        }
        return View(await computers.ToListAsync());
    }
```

I am running into an issue with my `searchPrice` and `searchDate` filters. I believe it has to do with the if not null check. If I comment out these 2 sections my code works fine so it has to be something within these 2 sections.

I have tried switching the > and < with <= and >= operators and I have also tried the `ToString` instead of concatenating the search criteria and none of it worked.

EDIT: The issue I am running into is that my method enters into the if statements for searchPrice and searchDate even if there is no user input, when it is supposed to skip all of the if statements and return all computers.

EDIT 2: I have altered my method to have all string parameters and parsing their respective values in their respective if statements. this has solved the problem of entering the if statements prematurely but now my logic is wrong. The searchPrice now works as it should, but the installationDate filter does not. It takes in the values properly but does not do the comparison correctly. for example, if I enter 11/14/2019 in the 1st and leave the other blank, it shows me computers with 11/15/2019 as the installation date when it should show computers with dates before 11/14/2019. switching the logical operators around did not fix it either.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: `if (String.IsNullOrEmpty("" + searchPrice1))` try to make this evaluate to `true`. I'd like to see that.

Comment: _" I believe it has to do with the if not null check."_ - There is no "is not null" check in that code. Except for the first two strings. But I am referring to the price and date sections ...

Comment: _"I am running into an issue"_ - what "isue"? An exception? Unexpected behavior?

Comment: But to actually help a little bit: `decimal` is a value type. It _cannot_ be null. Ever. `""` is an empty string, but not null. `"" + searchPrice1` will concat the empty string to `searchPrice1.ToString()`. Which will _never_ be null nor empty. `decimal?` would be a Nullable value type. But you still wouldn't check it like you do.

Comment: CompareTo returns three values -1 when left is less than right, 0 when left equals right, 1 when left is greater then right. I can't tell what you code is attempting to do.

Comment: Not just -1, but any negative value. Not just 1, but any positive (non-zero) value. It's important to do `< 0` or `> 0`, and not something like `== -1`. It's not the same as `IndexOf` where `-1` is the exact value returned for "not found".

Comment: `DateTime` _can_ be `null`. But: again, `"" + searchDate1` will _never_ be. Just check it with `if( searchDate1 is not null )` or on older versions `if ( !(searchDate1 is null) )` or the like.